# Kivy - Editable RecycleView

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

I'm trying to create an editable table with the RecycleView widget using a TextInput widget as the individual element in Kivy. By looking at the examples and some posts on the web, I was able to write a table that takes input from the user.

Now I'm trying to get which row did the user edit. I could find events for on_text of the text input but that doesn't give information about the row number. Also I tried looking at the events available for the RecycleView but couldn't get much help from it.

Could anyone of you guide me in the right path. I'm fairly new to kivy. I have attached herewith, a simple example that I'm working on.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<Row@BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    itemText: ''
    TextInput:
        id:CellText
        text:root.itemText


<RV>:
    id: rv
    viewclass: 'Row'
    scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
    scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
    bar_width: dp(10)
    RecycleGridLayout:
        cols:3
        default_size: None, dp(30) 
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(1)
''')


class RV(RecycleView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'itemText':'1'}, {'itemText':'John'}, {'itemText':'K'}, {'itemText':'2'}, {'itemText':'David'}, {'itemText':'P'}]


class rvTestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rvTestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SP SP's answer gets a way to work around this problem but I found another way (hoping this to be a better one) to get the row index.

Adding the below over-riding functions into the row class helped me get the row index when ever the user clicks on the textinput.

```
class Row(BoxLayout, RecycleDataViewBehavior):
index = None

def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
    ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
    self.index = index
    return super(Row, self).refresh_view_attrs(
        rv, index, data)

def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if super(Row, self).on_touch_down(touch):
        return True
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        global rowIndex
        rowIndex = self.index
```

Thanks again for helping me with your suggestions. Posting my solution in case if any one else is facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the following is recommandable but, to do that when I add a box in the recycle view data i pass it the recycle view instance and when the box is created I add it to a list of the recycle view so you can control the rv from each box and you can control each box from the rv:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string('''
<Row>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    itemText: ''
    TextInput:
        id:CellText
        text:root.itemText


<RV>:
    id: rv
    viewclass: 'Row'
    scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
    scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
    bar_width: dp(10)
    RecycleGridLayout:
        cols:3
        default_size: None, dp(30) 
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(1)
''')


class RV(RecycleView):
    list_items = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'itemText': '1', 'paren': self, 'index':0}, {'itemText': 'John', 'paren': self, 'index':1},
                 {'itemText': 'K', 'paren': self, 'index':2}, {'itemText': '2', 'paren': self, 'index':3},
                 {'itemText': 'David', 'paren': self, 'index':4}, {'itemText': 'P', 'paren': self, 'index':5}]

    def which_edit(self, *args):
        '''This will print the index of the box which is currently edited'''
        print args[0].parent.index 


class Row(BoxLayout):
    paren = ObjectProperty() #the instance of the rv

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.update)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.paren.list_items.append(self)
        self.ids.CellText.bind(text=self.paren.which_edit)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I think this will work fine even if it looks more like a work around.